# How do I use AppleScript to time program execution

Tags: applescript

I would like to use AppleScript to batch run a bunch of programs and get the time that each one ran.

Example: From the command line I would type `time ls` like this:

```
$ time ls
Applications 
bin
net
Library
... etc

real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.006s
```

but when I try to use apple script and put the results into a variable, it completely ignores the time output.

Example:

```
set result to do shell script "time ls"
```

returns

```
Applications 
bin
net
Library
... etc
```

with no mention of the time execution time anywhere.

Even making this more simple:

```
set result to do shell script "time"
```

returns

```
""
```

How do I get the time of execution back from AppleScript?

p.s. I'm not actually trying to time `ls`.  I want to time a bunch of custom created programs, but `ls` makes simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `exec 2>&1` command to redirect the **STDERR** to **STDOUT**, like this:

```
do shell script "exec 2>&1; time  ls"
```

Comment: I knew from the man page for `time` that its output was written to `stderr` and I tried every form of redirection I could think of and couldn't get it to work right. Now having seen and tried your answer I was curious as to how that worked. Obviously reading the output of `help exec`, as it's a `builtin`, gave me the answer. Nice solution! +1